# How to create valid URL to open RDP (Microsoft) in swift

Tags: swift, url, rdp

Hi i am facing issue after updating to iOS 17 and MacOS 14. I can't no more open
RDP (Microsoft) client from url in swift

i have url:

```
let urlString = "rdp://full%20address=s:\(serverURL))&audiomode=i:2&disable%20themes=i:1&username=s:\(userName)"
if let validURL = URL(string:urlString) { 
     NSWorkspace.shared.open(validUR)
}
```

in iOS lower than 17 it's working fine. It seems the parsing mechanism have problem with

```
:
```

I try to encode : with %3A but it doesn't work.
Can somebody guide me what I am missing or doing wrong?

Thank's .

Comment: There has been a change indeed. See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/url/3126806-init But I don't know the solution, might need to read more about that. Is `serverURL` percent escaped too? What if you try to create the URL with URLComponents?

Comment: Yes I did try to use URLComponents and same result (nil) also I did try encode server userName. Still without success

Comment: do you have a basic/miniimal example `rdp:` URL? You might need to troubleshoot up to the most complex version....

If you think it is the first ":", can you try setting the URL scheme, then putting the rest of the URL in via other parts of the framework?

Answer (score 1):

It works for me on macOS 14 if I replace *all* instances of `:` with `%3a`:

```swift
import Foundation
import AppKit

let s = "rdp://full%20address=s%3a192.168.1.26&username=s%3aAdministrator"
if let u = URL(string: s) {
  NSWorkspace.shared.open(u)
}
```